# Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (23000) SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'first_name' cannot be null

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am fairly new to laravel and am experiencing this problem when trying to input values in my db. this same thing work for the patients table and form but not for the doctors. if someone could point out where im going wrong that would be really appreciated

the table,

```
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('doctors', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('uid')->unique();
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->longText('address')->nullable();
            $table->longText('education')->nullable();
            $table->longText('specialist')->nullable();
            $table->date('dob');
            $table->string('blood_group',5);
            $table->enum('sex',['M','F','O']);
            $table->string('nid_file')->nullable();
            $table->string('cv_file')->nullable();
            $table->string('picture')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('status')->default(1);
            $table->unsignedInteger('designation_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('department_id');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('designation_id')->references('id')->on('designations')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('department_id')->references('id')->on('departments')->onDelete('cascade');
        });

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('doctors');
    }
}
```

the view through which i want to input values,

```
<div class="card card-tsk mb-4">
    <div class="card-body">
        <form action="{{route('doctor-reg.store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">@csrf
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="first_name">First Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="last_name">Last Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="phone">Phone No</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone No">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    {{-- <label for="designation">Designation</label>
                    <select name="designation" id="designation" class="form-control select2">
                        <option value="">Select Designation</option>
                        @foreach($designations as $designation)
                            <option value="{{$designation->id}}">{{$designation->name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select> --}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    {{-- <label for="department">Department</label>
                    <select name="department" id="department" class="form-control select2">
                        <option value="">Select Department</option>
                        @foreach($departments as $department)
                        <option value="{{$department->id}}">{{$department->name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                    </select> --}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="address">Address</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" name="address" id="address"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="Education">Education/Degree</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="education" rows="6" id="Education" ></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="specialist">Specialist</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="specialist" name="specialist" placeholder="Specialist">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="dob">Date fo Birth</label>
                    <input  class="form-control datepicker" id="dob"  name="dob" value="{{date('Y/m/d')}}" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="blood_group">Blood Group</label>
                    <select name="blood_group" id="blood_group" class="form-control select2">
                    <option value="">None</option>
                    <option value="A+">A+</option>
                    <option value="A-">A-</option>
                    <option value="B+">B+</option>
                    <option value="B-">B-</option>
                    <option value="AB+">AB+</option>
                    <option value="AB-">AB-</option>
                    <option value="O-">O-</option>
                    <option value="O+">O+</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="inputAddress2"  class="col-sm-2">Sex</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sex" id="sex1" checked value="M">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="sex1">Male</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sex" id="sex2" value="F">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="sex2">Female</label>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="nid_file">Upload NID <span class="help-block">(eg:pdf) </span></label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="nid_file" name="nid_file">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="cv_file">Upload Biography <span class="help-block">(eg:pdf) </span></label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="cv_file" name="cv_file">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="picture">Picture <span class="help-block">(eg:jpg) </span></label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="picture" name="picture">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="inputAddress2"  class="col-sm-2">Status</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="status" id="status1" checked value="1">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="status1">Active</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="status" id="status2" value="0">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="status2">Inactive</label>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-tsk"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Reset</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-tsk"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</button>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

i apologize for the huge code but i havent been able to fix this after numerous attempts and hope am giving a better context this way.

the controller,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Model\Department;
use App\Model\Designation;
use App\Model\Doctor;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Image;
class DoctorRegister extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @var Doctor
     */
    public $doctor;
    /**
     * @var Department
     */
    public $department;
    /**
     * @var Designation
     */
    public $designation;

    public function __construct(Doctor $doctor,Department $department,Designation $designation)
    {
        $this->doctor = $doctor;
        $this->department = $department;
        $this->designation = $designation;
    }

    public function index(){
        return view('auth.doctor-reg');
    }
    public function create(){
    }
    public function store(Request $request){

     $doctor =new $this->doctor;
     $doctor->first_name = $request->input('fname');
     $doctor->last_name = $request->input('lname');
     $doctor->username = $request->input('username');
     $doctor->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
     $doctor->phone = $request->input('phone');
     $doctor->email = $request->input('email');
     $doctor->designations = $request->input('designation');
     $doctor->departments = $request->input('department');
     $doctor->address = $request->input('address');
     $doctor->education = $request->input('education');
     $doctor->specialist = $request->input('specialist');
     $doctor->dob = $request->input('dob');
     $doctor->blood_group = $request->input('blood_group');
     $doctor->sex = $request->input('sex');
     $doctor->plan = $request->input('plan');
     $doctor->cabin = $request->input('cabin');
     $doctor->time = $request->input('time');
     $doctor->day = $request->input('day');
     $doctor->transaction_id = 1;
        if($request->hasFile('nid_file')){
            $nid_file_name = 'nid_'.time().'.pdf';
            $nid_file = $request->file('nid_file');
            $nid_file->move('assets/images/doctor/nid_file',$nid_file_name);
            $doctor->nid_file = $nid_file_name;
        }
        if($request->hasFile('cv_file')){
            $cv_file_name = 'cv_'.time().'.pdf';
            $cv_file = $request->file('cv_file');
            $cv_file->move('assets/images/doctor/cv_file',$cv_file_name);

            $doctor->cv_file = $cv_file_name;
        }
        if($request->hasFile('picture'))
        {
            $picture_path = 'assets/images/doctor/picture/pic_'.time().'.jpg';
            Image::make($request->picture)->resize(200, 200)->save($picture_path);
        }
     $doctor->nid_file = $request->nid_file;
     $doctor->cv_file = $request->cv_file;
     $doctor->picture = $request->picture;
     $doctor->status = $request->status;
     $doctor->save();
     return redirect('/login')->with('success','Doctor has been save successful');
    }

    public function edit($id){
        $doctor =$this->doctor->findOrFail($id);
        $departments = $this->department->orderBy('name')->get();
        $designations = $this->designation->orderBy('name')->get();
        return view('admin.doctor.edit',compact('doctor','departments','designations'));
    }
    public function update(Request $request,$id){

        $this->validate($request,[
            'first_name'=>'required',
            'last_name'=>'required',
            'username'=>'required|unique:doctors,username,'.$id,
            'phone'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required|email',
            'designation'=>'required',
            'department'=>'required',
            'nid_file'=>'mimes:pdf|max:2048',
            'cv_file'=>'mimes:pdf|max:2048',
            'picture'=>'mimes:jpg|max:2048',

        ]);
        $doctor =$this->doctor->findOrFail($id);
        $doctor->first_name = $request->first_name;
        $doctor->last_name = $request->last_name;
        $doctor->username = $request->username;
        $doctor->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $doctor->phone = $request->phone;
        $doctor->email = $request->email;
        $doctor->designation_id = $request->designation;
        $doctor->department_id = $request->department;
        $doctor->address = $request->address;
        $doctor->education = $request->education;
        $doctor->specialist = $request->specialist;
        $doctor->dob = $request->dob;
        $doctor->blood_group = $request->blood_group;
        $doctor->sex = $request->sex;
        if($request->hasFile('nid_file')){
            @unlink('assets/images/doctor/nid_file/'.$request->nid_file);
            $nid_file_name = 'nid_'.time().'.pdf';
            $nid_file = $request->file('nid_file');
            $nid_file->move('assets/images/doctor/nid_file',$nid_file_name);

            $doctor->nid_file = $nid_file_name;
        }
        if($request->hasFile('cv_file')){
            @unlink('assets/images/doctor/cv_file/'.$request->cv_file);
            $cv_file_name = 'cv_'.time().'.pdf';
            $cv_file = $request->file('cv_file');
            $cv_file->move('assets/images/doctor/cv_file',$cv_file_name);

            $doctor->cv_file = $cv_file_name;
        }
        if($request->hasFile('picture'))
        {
            @unlink('assets/images/doctor/picture/'.$request->picture);
            $picture_name = 'pic_'.time().'.jpg';
            $picture_path = 'assets/images/doctor/picture/'.$picture_name;
            Image::make($request->file('picture'))->resize(200, 200)->save($picture_path);
            $doctor->picture = $picture_name;
        }



        $doctor->status = $request->status;
        $doctor->save();
        return redirect()->to(route('admin.doctor'))->with('success','Data has been updated');

    }
    public function view($id){
        $doctor =$this->doctor->findOrFail($id);
        return view('admin.doctor.view',compact('doctor'));
    }
}
```

Update: Got it working, thanks to everyone who went through this big post and replied.

Comment: Hi, Rohan, please add nullable() at the end of this line ($table->string('first_name');) if you want to pass null first name.

Comment: where is `first_name` filed ? in your form ?

Comment: can you show your controller? and model?

Comment: @Hamelraj its in the second block of code.

Comment: @NiketJoshi i do not want to pass a nullable and thats why im having this problem

Comment: Then please show me controller code or you have to validate it Either from backend or from front-end

Comment: in your save function check dd($request->all()). check u get first_name value ? if not ok  show me your code save function ?

Comment: @codeformoney just updated and put up the controller code

Comment: you're input name is `first_name` but you call `fname` to your **request**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$doctor->first_name = $request->input('fname');
```

The request attributes should be accessed by the same name of the input in the form hence 'first_name'

```
$doctor->first_name = $request->input('first_name');
```

Also this applies to:

```
$doctor->last_name = $request->input('lname');
```

Should be:

```
$doctor->last_name = $request->input('last_name');
```

Comment: thanks for replying. that helped part of the problem, now im getting 'plan' cannot be null

Comment: I don't see any input in your form that has the name 'plan' neither does any of your table's columns, you need to double check it again.

Comment: 'plan' was present in the controller as "$doctor->plan = $request->input('plan');" and i commented it but then i get error "Field 'plan' doesn't have a default value"

Comment: Did you add it manually to the 'doctors' table?, if so then you need to add an input  named 'plan' in your form to be able to submit it to the controller then you can store it to your table.

Comment: As an example : `<div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="plan">Plan <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="plan" name="plan" placeholder="Plan">
                </div>`

Comment: No, this was actually a template on which a colleague was working before me and I started working on this project midway after he left. I'll try using the example and post back. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just tried it and it worked. Thanks a lot for all the help!

Comment: Don't forget to un-comment the assignment line in your controller `$doctor->plan = $request->input('plan');`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because in the migration the column *first_name* is not nullable. This means you have to give this column a value.

It's good practice to make these fields **required** in your form, so the user has to fill them out. Also, you can make use of server side [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation) to verify the posted request.

Answer (score 0):

The Exception `Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (23000) SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'first_name' cannot be null`
 itself says the error, Column `first_name` could not be null. You have to either set the column `first_name` nullable or You have to insert data.
Check your form, is it submitting data properly or not, and then check the controller from where you are inserting the data.

use `Validator` in controller before saving data. Here is the example,

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->input() , [
    'first_name' => 'required',
    'last_name' => 'required',
     ........
])
```

then you can check your request against the validator as

```
if($validation->fails()){
    //Validation failed
}else{
    //Success, process the request data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your see your the name for `input last_name` is `last_name` in your form

while in your `controller` you are looking for `$request->input('lname');` which is wrong

either change this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
```

to

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
```

or in your controller you can do this instead of `$request->input('lname');` you can just use `$request->input('last_name');` and the same goes for `firstname`

Thanks

Comment: yes i fixed that but now im getting 'plan' cannot be null

Comment: @RohanKorde i cannot seen input plan in your form,

Answer (score 0):

$request->input('first_name');  Or $request->first_name;